# Page number disappears in url during pagination in PHP/Magento

Tags: magento, pagination

:-)

I am currently working on making category pages SEO friendly by adding *rel="prev"* and *rel="next"* link. The page is dived into multiple pages with 12 product on each page - with a "page menu bar", just as normal pagination. I have followed [this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-implement-relprev-and-relnext-to-magentos-pagination/). Everything is working fine if I for example enter the url: *examplesite.com/tables.html?ajaxcatalog=true&p=2* (the source code contains the rel="prev" and rel="next" links with the right page numbers).

**But** - if I click on a page number (in the page menu bar), for example "2", in the menu bar. The page being opened are *examplesite.com/tables.html?ajaxcatalog=true&* and not containing the "p=2" even through the href="" of the buttom/link is correct if I inspect it.

I can really not figure out why the page number wont show in the url. Hope you can help me! I need the number in the url in order to show the correct prev and next link on the source code.

A weird thing is - If I enter the link *examplesite.com/tables.html?ajaxcatalog=true&amp%3B&p=2* and click around on the pages, the page number keeps being there - and everything functioning correctly!

An example of how the previous link (one page before the page I am at) is created:

```
<?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>
        <li>
            <a class="previous<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?> i-previous<?php endif;?>" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>">
```

The getPreviousPageUrl() does find the right url. Something happens with the link is clicked - which makes the page number disappear.

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 and the theme Porto from Smartvave.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that i applied :
In smartwave porto look for this file(**ajax.phtml**) in my case it located in here :

> \app\design\frontend\smartwave\porto\template\smartwave\ajaxcatalog\ajax.phtml

Find this line in that file

> "url.replace(page_param," ");"

somewhere around line **160** and **369**. and change that with this in both locations. Your pagination thing will work :)

> "url.replace(page_param,page_param);"

I'm attaching the block where you need to change this line.

```
var hist = url;
                        if(url.indexOf("p=") > -1){
                            var len = url.length-url.indexOf("p=");
                            var str_temp = url.substr(url.indexOf("p="),len);
                            var page_param = "";
                            if(str_temp.indexOf("&") == -1){
                                page_param = str_temp;
                            } else {
                                page_param = str_temp.substr(0,str_temp.indexOf("&"));
                            }
                            hist = url.replace(page_param,""); /* Change here !! */
                        }
```

Comment: Why not simply uncomment all that code block and add `var hist = url;` instead? :)